# Getting Invalid JSON in request body everytime

Tags: node.js, json, request, form-data

I am trying to make a post request on url https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/subscription-plans using node js requests but getting this body in return:

```
{"status":"ERROR","subCode":"400","message":"Invalid JSON in request body"}
```

This is my Code:

```
        var querystring = require('querystring');
        var request = require('request');

        var form = {
            planId: "NJGRKON12354",
            planName: "Rent Product",
            type: "PERIODIC",
            amount: 100,
            intervalType: "month",
            intervals: 1
            
        };

        var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
        var contentLength = formData.length;

        
        request({
            headers: {
                'X-Client-Id': 'XXXXX',
                'X-Client-Secret': 'XXXXXX',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            uri: 'https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/subscription-plans',
            body: formData,
            method: 'POST'
        }, function (error1, res1, body) {
            console.log('statusCode:', res1.statusCode);
            console.log("Body: ", body);
        });
```

When i try with same headers and body in postman its Running.

[Postman Hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9MOL.png)

Comment: You are sending string not json. Try to remove `stringify`

Comment: did you try this `body: JSON.stringify(form),`